# How to backup bookmark for spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, bookmarks

I want to re-install spacemacs, since something doesn't work and I don't want to spent on fix it. But how to backup the bookmarks of the spacemacs, even better also backup the most recent open file list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spacemacs saves the bookmarks in `~/.emacs.d/.cache/bookmarks`, and the recent files lise in `~/.emacs.d/.cache/recentf`. You can copy these two files somewhere outside of `~/.emacs.d`, and copy them back in after re-installing.

In fact, there might be more files in `~/.emacs.d/.cache` that you'd like to save. I suggest backing up the entire `~/.emacs.d/.cache` and restoring what you miss after re-installation.

For completeness, I'll mention that the locations of these two files are controlled by the variables `bookmark-default-file` and `recentf-save-file`.

Comment: Cache to me always implies softstate, why would you place curated bookmarks in a folder which you should be able to delete without much thought? This does not follow the principle of least surprise.